# Should I use a lower resolution because of lens sharpness?

Tags: nikon, sharpness, nikon-d5300

I am using the Nikon D5300 with the kit 18-55mm VR lens. According to DXOMark, the sharpness with that lens is only 9 Megapixels. Is it worth shooting at 24 Megapixels if the lens is only resolving 9?

Here is the link to the DXOMark Page.
http://www.dxomark.com/Lenses/Nikon/AF-S-DX-Nikkor-18-55mm-f-3.5-5.6G-VR-mounted-on-Nikon-D5300__919

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, these scores are somewhat misleading. Clearly, the 18-55mm delivers far less than 24 MP of details but they are not uniformly distributed and also vary by aperture and focal-length. What you would do by shooting at around 9 MP is ensure that you get no more than 9 MP of details. If you aim for 16 MP around, it would probably be better and you would still save storage and image processing times by having smaller files.